# Incredible shot by/from Ronaldo

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

“An incredible shot from Ronaldo” said the commentator.

I think it should be ‘by Ronaldo’ but I’ve heard a lot of people use the words interchangeably. 
Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

**Both are correct**.

Definition of **"from"** (Cambridge Dictionary):

> used to show the origin of something or someone

This works because **Ronaldo is the origin** of the shot, without him there wouldn't be that shot.

Therefore, **"from"** works here.

---

Definition of **"by"** (Cambridge Dictionary):

> used to show the person or thing that does something

This works because  it is **Ronaldo who perform** the shot, and he is the doer/ performer.

Therefore, **"with"** works here also.

In many circumstances, several prepositions can be used interchangeably.